# Load page and highlight anchor div using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, highlight

I'm trying to setup my anchor tags in a way similar to StackOverflow where if I'm on Page A and click on a link to a div on Page B, the div is highlighted via jQuery UI's, *highlight* feature. What I'm having trouble  figuring out is how to pass the anchor link to the new page and highlight it. Here is the page scenario.

**Page A**

```
...
<a href="/albums/1#track-1
```

**Page B**

```
<!-- /albums/1#track-1 -->

<div class="tracklist">
  ...
  <div id="track-1" class="track">Track 1</div> <!-- Highlights this div -->
  <div id="track-2" class="track">Track 2</div>
  <div id="track-3" class="track">Track 3</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Aside from the setup itself I have a few performance concerns. Ideally I'm thinking that you'd have to loop through every `.track` on **every page load**, regardless if those particular divs are on the page. What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote wrong the ids in your html code, remove the '#' symbol. Something like the following will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href; // Returns full current url.
  var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);

  $('#' + hash).effect('highlight', {color: '#00f'}, 2000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/f6qohfb8/

Comment: The problem with this is that the url would need to be dynamic. There would need to be a way to get the url without hardcoding a value in the script.

Comment: @CarlEdwards `window.location.href;` returns the full current url.

Comment: If I'm following you, you're suggesting that the value of `url` would be `window.location.href`?

Comment: Yes, this way you can get the hash.

Comment: The only thing that concerns me is that this is gonna fire for every page load. There's no way to avoid that?

Comment: @CarlEdwards you can place the js code in the page B or add a condition before running the full script.

Comment: Okay thanks. Before I mark this as correct would you mind just changing the value for the `url` variable to `window.location.href` for future reference?

Comment: Great. Thanks again for your help.